# Error de RCP en WebLogic. No conecta a la base de datos

Tags: weblogic

En WebLogic hago el deploy del war, la conexión a la base de datos es a través de JNDI. Mi proyecto funciona correctamente por un tiempo pero después ya no realiza la conexión y solo vuelve a funcionar cuando elimino el Destino del JNDI y lo vuelvo a agregar.

El error que me envía es:

> org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: error code [930059]; RPC error:Se ha forzado la interrupciÃ³n de una conexiÃ³n existente por el host remoto;

La configuración de mi JNDI en mi proyecto es:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="siseDataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/MC"/>

<bean id="siseJdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="siseDataSource" />
</bean>
```

Comment: revisa los parámetros de conexión de tu base de datos, me refiero a si tienes restricciones de algún tipo